# Unity Factory Injection

Tags: c#, unity-container, castle

I have an interface like the below one which I inject into unity container.

```
public interface IMyInstanceFactory
{
    IEnumerable<IMyInstance> GetAll();
}
```

All `IMyInstance` are known before runtime i.e they can be setup within the bootstrapper and can be retrieved from unity. My concrete implementation for `IMyInstanceFactory` is as below:

```
public class MyInstanceFactory:IMyInstanceFactory
{
    IUnityContainer _container;

    public MyInstanceFactory(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }
    public IEnumerable<IMyInstance> GetAll()
    {
        return _container.ResolveAll<IMyInstance>();
    }
}
```

..and in my bootstrapper I do something like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IMyInstance,MyInstance1>;
container.RegisterType<IMyInstance,MyInstance2>;
container.RegisterType<IMyInstance,MyInstance3>;
container.RegisterType<IMyInstanceFactory,MyInstanceFactory>;
```

This resolves everything beautifully. However, I do not want to take a dependency on the the container as such or implement `IMyInstanceFactory` just for this, is there a way I can set this up without implementing `IMyInstanceFactory`? Does Unity provide a facility for this?

Something of this sort..

```
container.RegisterType<IMyInstanceFactory,factory=>factory.GetAll()>().IsResolvedBy(unity.ResolveAll<IMyInstance>);
```

I know castle can do this, can Unity do something similar?

Comment: If that is really all your factory does, why not just use the unity container directly?  Or if you want don't want your code to be dependent on Unity, you could use IServiceLocator.

Comment: Please don't use a ServiceLocator. This is [considered an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx) in modern application architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a port of the Castle Windsor Typed Factory Facilities for Unity](http://outlawtrail.wordpress.com/2012/07/27/auto-generated-factories-with-unity/). It will generate an implementation of your interface and do the `ResolveAll` for you.

Your bootstrapping code should look something like this:

```cs
container.RegisterType<IMyInstance,MyInstance1>("1");
container.RegisterType<IMyInstance,MyInstance2>("2");
container.RegisterType<IMyInstance,MyInstance3>("3");
container.RegisterType<IMyInstanceFactory>(new TypedFactory());
```

The call to `GetAll` will be translated to the container call `ResolveAll`.

The port follows the same conventions described for Windsor.

Comment: Okay, but how do you register an actual factory? -- Like, for a class with no public constructor, (and you don't want to register a specific instance) -- how do you register a Func<T> instead so that the container can create the object from scratch when it needs it.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 You can use a regular factory by using an `InjectionFactory`
`var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IFoo>(new InjectionFactory(c => Foo.Create()));
IFoo foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>();

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    private Foo() { }
    public static Foo Create()
    {
        return new Foo();
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in passing a container to a factory, this works well if the factory is exposed as a singleton so that getting an instance does not require passing the container once again.

Another option would be to resolve the container with a service locator in a factory, since the locator is a singleton, this approach resembles the former.

Comment: If you implement a container based factory you should watch where you place that factory. See the paragraph about [Container-based factories](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementingAnAbstractFactory.aspx).

Comment: @SebastianWeber: even if the factory is composed in the Composition Root, you still have to access it SOMEHOW from your application. That's why I mention a singleton. I don't think any other option exists beside these three: two that I mention (a factory which depends on the container and is exposed as a singleton vs a transient factory which does not depend on the container and accesses the service locator directly) and the one which is not practical (a transient factory which has an explicit dependence to the container).

Comment: Why should a transient factory with a dependency on the container not be solveable? Make the factory a private class inside your composition root. Map from interface to that implementation. Unity registers itself inside the container. When you resolve the private implementation the container will be injected into it. Your app only has dependencies on the factory interface. Done.

Comment: @SebastianWeber: and how do you resolve with no container at hand? In a sense - I have an arbitrary method Foo in arbitrary class Bar and I want to resolve the factory? I'd have to make Bar dependent on the container OR the Composition Root (which is not possible if Bar is deep in a library and the Composition Root sits in the main module).

Comment: Sorry I don't get your point. Some component in your app has a dependency on the factory interface. In the composition root you register all dependencies, resolve the root object of the application and the container takes care of creating the objects for you and injects them where appropriate. The container itself does not appear anywhere outside the composition root. It will inject the private factory implementation into consumers and they will only see the factory interface but never the implementation.

Comment: @SebastianWeber: two modules, a DLL A and a main application B. B references A. The factory interface is defined in A. My composition root sits in B (according to the recommendation, it should sit in `Main`/`Global.asax`). Because B references A and circular dependency is not possible, I cannot reference B from A. Now I add a utility class to A. From one of its methods I need to resolve the factory. I have the interface (because it is also in A). But how do I resolve the interface not having the container and not having an access to the composition root?

Comment: You inject the factory interface into your utility class?! And if that utility class is static you make the interface a method parameter an make sure you inject the factory interface into the caller of your utility class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20753/discussion-between-wiktor-zychla-and-sebastian-weber)