# How should I choose an instance of an AbstractFactory?

Tags: c#, architecture, abstract-factory

Currently I'm having a trouble with instantiating an AbstractFactory. There are some classes:

```
abstract class ABase { }
class A1 : ABase { }
class A2 : ABase { }

abstract class BBase { }
class B1 : BBase
{
    private readonly A1 _a;
    public B1(A1 a)
    {
        _a = a;
    }
}
class B2 : BBase
{
    private readonly A2 _a;
    public B2(A2 a)
    {
        _a = a;
    }
}


abstract class FactoryBBase
{
    abstract public BBase Create(ABase b);
}
class FactoryB1 : FactoryBBase
{
    override public BBase Create(ABase b)
    {
        return new B1(b as A1);
    }
}
class FactoryB2 : FactoryBBase
{
    override public BBase Create(ABase b)
    {
        return new B2(b as A2);
    }
}

class Runtime
{
    public void ProcessA(ABase a)
    {
        //How should I choose a proper factory?
    }
}
```

How do I instantiate a proper abstract factory in `ProcessA` method depending on the type of `a`? The thing is that I don't want to have a big if/else block.

Answer (score 1):

> how to instantiate a proper abstract factory in ProcessA method depending on the type of a?

To avoid big if/else block you can put all factories into a map, where key is the type of `a` and value is the implementation. in Java I would do this either by Spring or I would create a static code, that can initialize the map when the class is loaded.

> do I use AbstractFactory pattern as it is supposed to be uesd?

IMHO yes.

Comment: My current solution is something like this. I find it OK, but I'm hoping that there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

How to implement abstract factory really depends on what you need. What you have there is indeed a proper implementation, but I think it's not exactly what you need since you want to do something differently dependending on the type or state of an instance of `ABase`.

The logic that analyses the type or state is exactly what I'd put into a factory.

```
abstract class ABase { }
class A1 : ABase { }
class A2 : ABase { }

public abstract class FactoryBBase
{
    public abstract IProcessor Create(ABase a);
}
public class ConcreteFactory : FactoryBBase
{
    override public IProcessor Create(ABase a)
    {
        // this is ugly for a large amount of ABase implementations of course
        if (a is A1)
        {
            return new Runtime1();
        }
        if (a is A2)
        {
            return new Runtime2();
        }
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}

public interface IProcessor
{
    void ProcessA(ABase a);
}

public class Runtime1 : IProcessor
{
    public void ProcessA(ABase a)
    {
        // process away
    }
}

public class Runtime2 : IProcessor
{
    public void ProcessA(ABase a)
    {
        // process away differently
    }
}
```

Multiple factory implementations come into play when you want the **same** type of `ABase` implementation to be processed by **different** types of Runtime/Processor depending on state that is outside of `ABase`.

Comment: Not exactly, I would like to do the same thing with different instances of `BBase`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookup dictionary instead of a if-else/switch construct.

```
//classes used as markers
public interface IMarker {}
public class MarkerA : IMarker {}
public class MarkerB : IMarker {}

//classes to be created
public interface IData {}
public class DataA : IData {}
public class DataB : IData {}

//factory to call abstract factories (could use static here)
public class Factory
{
    public IData Create(IMarker marker)
    {
        //lookup dictionary instead of if/switch
        //func ensures instance is only created when required
        var lookup = new Dictionary<Type, Func<DataFactoryBase>>()
        {
            { typeof(MarkerA), () => new DataAFactory() },
            { typeof(MarkerB), () => new DataBFactory() },
        };

        //get factory by type and call constructor
        return lookup[marker.GetType()]().Create();
    }
}

//abstract factories
public abstract class DataFactoryBase
{
    public abstract IData Create();
}

public class DataAFactory : DataFactoryBase
{
    public override IData Create()
    {
        return new DataA();
    }
}

public class DataBFactory : DataFactoryBase
{
    public override IData Create()
    {
        return new DataB();
    }
}


public static void Main()
{
    //example will return DataA 
    IData data = new Factory().Create(new MarkerA());   
}
```

Comment: The thing that bothers me is that `Factory` knows about all the possible implementations. They can be situated in different namespaces/projects/dlls, and `Factory` has to reference them all.  
That can be a problem in my case.

Comment: Try using dependency injection, e.g. Ninject. https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki

Comment: I do use Unity, but I don't know how to apply it to solve the problem.

Comment: Hmm, is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749706/unity-factory-injection

Comment: It is a very interesting approach. I've got to try it.